# How to read from list<object> and save it as a string?

Tags: java, notifications

i have a list and i have to get elements from it to a string. 
Ive been searching a web some time now and still no luck.

So i am getting my list from chapter.getFacts(Language.en) - objects look like this (com.xxx.models.Fact@4215fd98, com.xxx.models.Fact@435291e8, com.xxx.models.Fact@43529318 ...).Every one of that object contains address, telephone number, website etc..
I should read their content and should save them to one string that i can represent to user.

Can u help me out here? tnx

```
public class Fact implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8839726094517932950L;
public static final String COLUMN_LANGUAGE = "language";
public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_ID = "locationId";
public static final String COLUMN_GUIDE_ID = "guideId";
public static final String COLUMN_TRIP_ID = "tripId";

/** the locationId it is associated with **/
@DatabaseField(uniqueCombo = true)
private int locationId;

@DatabaseField(uniqueCombo = true)
private int guideId;

@DatabaseField(uniqueCombo = true)
private int tripId;

/** the language of the Guide **/
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.ENUM_STRING, uniqueCombo = true)
private Language language;

/** the name of the guide in the specified language **/
@DatabaseField()
private String value;

/** **/
@DatabaseField()
private String type;

/**
 * Actually, this field holds enum {@link com.tripwolf.models.FactType},
 * but ORMLites unknownEnumName mechanism uses reflection each time to detect enum value if it was not found,
 * which adds unacceptable peformance impact,
 * so we need to use custom getter and setter to handle unknown FactTypes
 */
@DatabaseField(uniqueCombo = true)
private int typeId;

/**
 * @return the locationId
 */
public int getLocationId() {
    return locationId;
}

/**
 * @param locationId the locationId to set
 */
public void setLocationId( int locationId ) {
    this.locationId = locationId;
}

/**
 * @return the language
 */
public Language getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

/**
 * @param language the language to set
 */
public void setLanguage( Language language ) {
    this.language = language;
}

/**
 * @return the value
 */
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

/**
 * @param value the value to set
 */
public void setValue( String value ) {
    this.value = value;
}

/**
 * @return the type
 */
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public FactType getTypeEnum() {
    return FactType.getType(typeId);
}

/**
 * @param type the type to set
 */
public void setType( String type ) {
    this.type = type;
}

/**
 * @return the typeId
 */
public FactType getTypeId() {
    return FactType.getType(typeId);
}

/**
 * @param typeId the typeId to set
 */
public void setTypeId( FactType typeId ) {
    this.typeId = typeId.ordinal();
}

public int getGuideId() {
    return guideId;
}

public void setGuideId( int guideId ) {
    this.guideId = guideId;
}

public int getTripId() {
    return tripId;
}

public void setTripId( int tripId ) {
    this.tripId = tripId;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to at least post the code for the Fact class.

Comment: Override the `toString` method in your `Fact` class.

Answer (score 1):

In your fact class, implement toString method which is getting called when you say try to print time as above and since its absent, it calls Object's toString default implementation and you see the output with hash code along iwth the class name. Define toString sometthing like below:

```
class Fact {
    String address;
    String website;
    //other business logic and getter/setter constructor stuff if any
    public String toString() {
        return address + " " + website;
    }
}
```

Once you do this and say print your list, you will see output something like:

```
[myaddress1 website1, myaddress2 website2]
```

Comment: show us the code that you have i.e. fact class and where you are populating facts and where you are printing facts. I still don't see toString in your Fact class.